# Run two nodejs instances through nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am able to get One Node instances instead of two. I don't know why my Second Node is not running
First Would like to tell that what I am done.

1. Download Nginx on c drive.
   Folder contains

> conf-> Under this Folder have config file i.e nginx.conf

Now I Want To run two node instances through nginx.
What I did on nginx.conf file is:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 81;

        server_name localhost;
        location /test {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }   
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

So my first Node js instance runs on http://127.0.0.1:3000 while another one is on http://127.0.0.1:3001 port.
This is my first time I am using nginx with node instances.
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: is there a *question*

Comment: What is your problem now? Do you want to map two different domains to these two nodeJs processes with Nginx?

Comment: Yes. It Loads Only  my first URL i.e http://127.0.0.1:3000.

Comment: @karthikdivi yes. I updated  the question.

Comment: I think you can try this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/setting-up-multiple-nodejs-applications-using-nginx-vitual-hosts

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see the question. Both node instances are available at http://localhost (3000) and http://localhost:81 (3001)

Comment: According to the config, you should be hitting localhost:80 and localhost:81 to access those instances through nginx. What exactly are you trying which is failing?

Comment: @maaw I am able to run only One Server of node instead of two. Like if i Type localhost/ then it deals with server 1 and if i type localhost/test then it have to deal with only server 2 not 1. And that is my question

Comment: @ChiragRavindra if I change both servers on Port 80 then also only my first node instance work and if I type localhost/test then the second server not work. I updated the question. Please go through it. And really appreciate for giving time to this

Comment: @ChiragRavindra ok. So If i will use different port like server 1: on port 80 and another one for 81, then also it picks the first one

Comment: So I am going to make edit on my question which is first server on port 80 and another on port 81

Comment: @ChiragRavindra ok. So If I will use the different port like server 1: on port 80 and another one for 81, then also it picks the first one. When I type localhost:81/test it return nodejs cannot found page error i.e "Cannot GET /test"

Comment: @Abhay You can proxy more servers in one port. The concept is all your requests will come through one port and from there you can decide that to which server the request should go

Comment: First add two location blocks (/ and /test) in a single server block (default http port is 80). So choose 80 0r 443 (http or https). Make sure that your two servers are working and hit 127.0.0.1/ and 127.0.0.1/test respectively. Now you will definitely see the expected result

Comment: @ganka Can you do me a favor. Please copy my code and add the things which you would like to tell. If You can. Anyways Thanks for suggesting anything

Comment: @ganka I do these things but also getting same response that is "Cannot GET /test"

Comment: In your 2nd server, Have you expect the app path from "test/****"? If not add that path also into your middleware router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if Anyone wants to run two node Instances on Single port through nginx then on nginx->conf->nginx.conf page just add these things

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /test {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Now my nginx server can hold 2 node js instances.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have two different pages such as page1.com and page2.com and they are set in hosts file correctly, use default port for both which is 80 and set domain names as server_name as below;

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name page1.com www.page1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name page1.com www.page1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }   
}
```